# Is there a way to distinguish a calendar month vs the following 30 days?

Tags: tiempo, ambigüedad

I was looking at the sentence:

> Tienes planes para el mes que viene

and it got me wondering how to distinguish between plans for the next calendar month (March) and plans for the next 30 days. If I'm wondering about the next 30 days (Feb 23 to March 24), is there a way to use "mes"?

I'm similarly wondering about other periods of time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to disambiguate between “the next calendar month” and “the next 30 days” if you use *“el mes que viene”*. The intended meaning is the former, generally. So for the latter meaning it is best to be explicit and say *“los próximos treinta días”*. Change appropriately for other periods of time (e.g., *“el año que viene”* vs. *“los próximos doce meses”*). You can certainly make the other meaning explicit too by using the expressions *mes calendario* or *año calendario*, but those are a bit formal.

Comment: Tal como en inglés, pues.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [pablodf76's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/40247/14867), in general, if you say *"el mes que..."* then it is taken to mean one of those things called months and having names (e.g. february, march). Whereas if you say something like *"durante un mes"* or *"no nos veremos por dos meses"*, in the sense of duration, then it tends to be taken to mean such duration starting from any arbitrary point in time, not necessarily the first day of a month.

This is the same with hours, years, *"quincenas"*: *"voy a entrenar por un año para preparme para la maratón"*, *"el año que viene es 2023"*. Though "la próxima hora" can be ambiguous, I think.

Answer (score 1):

*Que tal?*

- En Español no solemos especificar tanto, a no ser que sea una cuestión de trabajo y la persona tenga una *agenda*, un cuadre mensual ó una especie de *planing* en el que desarrolle su actividad y pueda de modo efectivo determinarlo. De ser así, nos referimos a ello especificando. Ejem. ¿Cómo tienes el mes?. ¿Cómo has cuadrado el mes ó Marzo...?. ¿Qué harás hasta el próximo 24 de Marzo?, ya que sobrentendemos que en ese espacio temporal pueden existir reuniones, viajes, ferias comerciales...
- De forma coloquial, normalmente el espacio temporal se alarga, ya que intuimos que los *planes* suelen cambiar, y más que por mes ó meses, hablamos ó empleamos periodos más largos. La palabra *plan* ó *agenda* es una buena opción. Ejem. ¿Qué *planes* tienes para este verano?. ¿Qué harás esta primavera? ó hasta fin de año. Puedes conocer a la persona y saber que toma vacaciones o va a realizar algún tipo de actividad en un momento determinado, pero sin concretar. ¿Tienes algún plan para Marzo?. ¿Cuál es la agenda... mensual...para tu próximo....trimestre...?
- En otros aspectos temporales suele pasar igual, utilizando las horas, próximas horas, por días, próximos días, en esta semana, por semanas, durante estas semanas... ó especificando aspectos temporales muy concretos, vacaciones, semana santa, navidad, el día de tu cumpleaños...

Espero haber ayudado. Saludos. Diego.